# Turn android opencv camera prepair for OCR

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera, ocr

I am going to create an android app which can capture the document paper to do OCR by using opencv camera. I am looking for the best way to turn opencv camera to get OCR optimize images (focus on document text, make text clearer) before OCR process. 
I know there are some pre-processing image methods before OCR, but I want to **get OCR optimize input sources** before process them, for example, by using `CvCameraViewListener2` to process frame.
Is there any suggestion to do this?

Comment: I think when it comes to camera based document processing , the optimum way is not to rely too much on the input source. It is much easier to get robust algorithms which works even in noisy environments.

Comment: @Dib Can you explain more detail why the optimum way is not to rely too much on the input source?

Comment: OCR on camera images is difficult than on scaned documents.The reason are:-1) As an algorithm developer there is no prior idea what would be the environment where the camera image is taken.2) image produced by the camera depends on the environment & the internal camera calibration parameters. So,again lots of exceptions come into play while processing. If i have understood your query properly, you are depending on the input source to get optimized OCR result but then you are also assuming that user knows what environment is good for the OCR algorithm. But in my opinion that is too much to ask.

Comment: Because my app is doing everything automatically, so there is no option for users to choose. I know it is very hard, but I want to make it works better as it can. What I want to do is prepare the good input source for OCR, then apply the pre-processing image and do OCR. So you mean there is no option to make camera image source clearer when taking it?

Comment: Well, i cannot say surely aboy that. But in general,what people does is to deploy noise removal and robust camera text recognition algorithms. It converts the input image to OCR friendly image and yet does not depend (too much) on the input source camera. They assume some minimal clarity and convert it into images good for the core algorithms. In my opinion your app needs exactly this.